# serving using zinc and pharo

Tags: server, smalltalk, pharo

After working on zincs tutorial I want to serve an entire repo filled with .js, .html and .css files I created a firstpathsegment so that I upload all files to the sam place but then how to create a place to serve and store the files ? and how to upload them ?

Answer (score 1):

If you read on in the [tutorial](http://zn.stfx.eu/zn/zinc-http-components-paper.html), you'll find how to do that in the part 'Static file server'

```
(ZnServer startDefaultOn: 1701)
   delegate: (ZnStaticFileServerDelegate new
                directory: (FileDirectory on: '/var/www');
                prefixFromString: 'static-files';
                yourself).
```

If you compare that to the `ZnMonticelloServerDelegate` implementation, you'll see how to write files. If you want to be able to create subdirectories, take a look at `FileSystem-Core-Public`. In a public-facing site, you'll need to do something about authentication and access control. We mostly put an apache or nginx in front (and let that take care of the static files).